# C++ library for time-efficient 3D iso-surface extraction from octree type (irregular) data point

Tags: 3d, contour, extract, surface

I have been searching a solution for weeks and not very fruitful due to my limited knowledge in computational geometry and thus want to reach to this community for help. Here is my case, I have a 3D field defined on irregular data points (similar to octree grid, sparse at large scale and dense at a region of interest). As far as I know, to extract iso-surface Marching cube is out of the way as it handles regular grid points only. Interpretation using Voronoi tessellation based method can redefine the 3D field on regular grid, but the interpretation is slow in order to have a smooth iso-surface. Is there such an algorithm that can extract iso-surface efficiently from irregular data points? Would be even better if such an algorithm is implemented in a library for quick testing. Thanks.

[Irregular data points figure. The dots are grid points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvFNW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using multiple Marching Cubes subdividing the domain where the point density is homogeneous?

http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/

Comment: Subdividing is a good idea, as the scalar 3D field is sampled multiple times each time with denser grid and smaller volume. Each time the sampled grid is regular, so I can extract one iso-surface from each set of samples, but not clear to me how to "stitch" multiple iso-surfaces.

Comment: Stitching will not be easy, I would try the same because those small cracks could be negligible.